# Como exportar uma página HTML/C#(Razor) que contem elementos SVG para PDF?

Tags: c#, html, pdf, svg, razor

Estou atualmente trabalhando com Highcharts, uma biblioteca javascript que gera gráficos. Ela possui um componente de exportação, porém só exporta o gráfico em si, ainda preciso montar o layout do PDF.

Para a exportação ele vai até o servidor highcharts.com o que não é o mais adequado também pois talvez a aplicação precise rodar offline.

Alguém tem experiência nessa exportação de SVG com HTML? Tem alguma dica de componente para ajudar nesse trabalho, de preferencia que rode offline?

Não achei necessário postar código nesse post, mas ajudaria qualquer código de exemplo ou alguma referência externa.

Comment: O pedido de links não vai ajudar sua pergunta. Como somos uma plataforma de perguntas e respostas. O link apenas não é considerado uma resposta. E a pergunta incentiva isso. Ela precisa fazer o contrário, incentivar respostas verdadeiras que não seja apenas link.

Comment: Entendi @bigown. Concordo com você. Sugeri os links achando que facilitaria uma resposta. Para mim o melhor mesmo seria postarem um exemplo de código e algumas referência, mas achei que era pedir demais.

Comment: Excluí minha resposta pois relendo acho que não é bem o que você quer saber (caso não tenha lido, sugeria deixar o browser gerar uma imagem usando um canvas, as funções de exportação do highcharts, e uma biblioteca externa). Eu acho que a pergunta ainda está um pouco confusa. Você quer fazer o processo todo no lado do servidor, ou quer um browser envolvido? O highcharts permite ambas opções (e, no caso de usar browser, permite usar seu próprio servidor em vez do highcharts.com).

Comment: Já tentou este? https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF/

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro o [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Para o seu caso específico provavelmente o link abaixo ajude:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

Uma vez instalado o phantomjs, crie um arquivo `htmltopdf.js`:

```js
// Usage: htmltopdf.js url pdf
var system = require('system');
var webpage = require('webpage');

var args = system.args;
var url = args[1];
var pdf = args[2];

var page = webpage.create();
page.open(url, function () {
    page.render(pdf);
    phantom.exit();
})
```

Depois, na linha de comando execute:

```
phantomjs htmltopdf.js http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

Ele vai gerar um arquivo pdf (google.pdf) da url (www.google.com).

Comment: Como faço pra acessar a linha de comando pela minha aplicação?

Comment: Aí já é outra pergunta. Digo, literalmente, a ser feita neste site. Mas, em Java, basta utilizar a classe Process/ProcessBuilder. Certamente há algo análogo em C#.